# Mysql Datetime with Time zone

Tags: mysql, datetime

I need a help in how to store datetime along with timezone. i am using Mysql 5.1. 
i want to do something like -

```
create table tb1
(
c1 datetime with time zone
);
```

Answer (score 6):

Save the timezone in an extra column or do the conversion before saving the datetime value depending on your needs.

Starting from Mysql 4.1.3 you can use the [`CONVERT_TZ()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz)

Answer (score 0):

You need Postgresql for that: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-datetime.html